# Exchange case in proving interpolation theorem by induction on the length of proof tree

Tags: logic, interpolation, sequent-calculus

I'm trying to prove Craig's interpolation theorem of propositional logic using Maehara's method by induction on the length of proof tree using sequent calculus. the theorem is as stated below:
$$ \forall \Gamma_1 \Gamma_2 \Delta_1 \Delta_2: \Gamma_1,\Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta_1,\Delta_2 $$
$$ \rightarrow \exists c: \Gamma_1 \vdash c,\Delta_1 \land c,\Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta_2$$
$$\land (atomsof(c) \subseteq  atomsof(\Gamma_1,\Delta_1) \cap atomsof(\Gamma_2,\Delta_2))$$
and here I'm stuck in the case where the proof ends by exchange rule like this:
$$ 
\frac{\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta,a,b,\Delta'}{\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta,b,a,\Delta'}$$
Here in induction hypotheses we have
$$ \forall \Delta_1' \Delta_2': \Delta,a,b,\Delta' = \Delta_1',\Delta_2' $$
$$ \rightarrow \exists c': \Gamma_1 \vdash c',\Delta_1' \land c',\Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta_2'$$
$$\land (atomsof(c) \subseteq  atomsof(\Gamma_1,\Delta_1') \cap atomsof(\Gamma_2,\Delta_2'))$$
and we have to deduce that
$$ \forall \Delta_1 \Delta_2: \Delta,b,a,\Delta' = \Delta_1,\Delta_2 $$
$$ \rightarrow \exists c: \Gamma_1 \vdash c,\Delta_1 \land c,\Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta_2$$
$$\land (atomsof(c) \subseteq  atomsof(\Gamma_1,\Delta_1) \cap atomsof(\Gamma_2,\Delta_2))$$
I'm stuck with the case where $\Delta_1 = \Delta,b $ and $ \Delta_2 = a,\Delta'$, I can't find the desired interpolant here, I couldn't find the original paper which is by the way written in Japanese. also I couldn't find the complete proof anywhere the closest I got was in "Proof Theory and logical complexity" by Jean-Yves Girard which even there he didn't cover exchange rule.

Comment: I may be missing something, but doesn’t it follow straightforwardly from the IH? That is, if the theorem holds for proofs of length $n$, then for the $n+1$ case, we have $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta, b, a, \Delta’$, which means in the $n$ case we had $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta, a, b, \Delta’$, which has the interpolation property by assumption. Sorry if I’m missing something crucial, but that’s my best guess.

Comment: @PW_246 The thing is we should prove the property for arbitrary $\Delta_1, \Delta_2$ and only thing we have is $\Delta, b, a, \Delta' = \Delta_1 , \Delta_2$ so both $\Delta$s are partitioned in several cases, in the case that is exactly in the middle of a and b i don't know how to construct the new interpolant

Comment: Again I may be mistaken, but wouldn’t $\Delta_1 = \Delta,b$ be the same thing as $\Delta_1’ = \Delta,b$?

Comment: In the hypothesis we can only have $\Delta_1' = \Delta,a$ since the order of b,a is reversed

Comment: I think it should work if you set $c=((c’ \land \neg b) \lor a)$, but I could just be wrong.

Comment: How do you prove 3rd condition ? That the atoms are included in intersection of acedent and sucedent.

Comment: I honestly don’t know.

Comment: Note: if you have structural rules, this means that the "order" of formulas matter. Thus, if the top seq is $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta, a, b, \Delta'$, how we derived it? With a rule that acts on the rightmost formula in $\Delta'$? If so you have only to "permute" Exchange prior to that rule and than apply it and what you get will be: $\Gamma_1, \Gamma_2 \vdash \Delta,  b, a, \Delta'$,

Comment: How do we know the theorem holds when we apply exchange rule prior to said rule ? we have to prove it at some point for the induction to work

Comment: Also I fixed some wrong things in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prove Craig's interpolation theorem for propositional logic using Maehara's method, I would propose to modify the calculus. Consider a similar calculus, where the left and right parts of sequents are finite multisets (instead of finite sequences). This modified calculus does not have explicit exchange rules. First, one can prove that the modified calculus is equivalent to the original one. After that, one can prove the theorem as you stated it (by induction).

Another approach would be to use finite sequences, but modify the claim that we prove by induction. We would need to consider sequents of the form $\Gamma_1^1,\Gamma_2^1,\Gamma_1^2,\Gamma_2^2,\ldots,\Gamma_1^k,\Gamma_2^k \vdash \Delta_1^1,\Delta_2^1,\Delta_1^2,\Delta_2^2,\ldots,\Delta_1^k,\Delta_2^k$ and construct an interpolant $c$ such that $\Gamma_1^1,\Gamma_1^2,\ldots,\Gamma_1^k \vdash c,\Delta_1^1,\Delta_1^2,\ldots,\Delta_1^k$ and $c,\Gamma_2^1,\Gamma_2^2,\ldots,\Gamma_2^k \vdash \Delta_2^1,\Delta_2^2,\ldots,\Delta_2^k$. The induction would be over proof length, as usual.